# Mac Desktop Client for FICS

Tags: macos

What are good chess clients for Mac, that allow playing on FICS. Nice-to-haves are an opening book, plug-and-play engines, and scoring of chess positions.

EDIT: For completeness, note that Jin does not allow you to save games. FICS can email them to you if you turn on a setting, but no way to recover guest games with Jin. I think this is a complete deal breaker.

Comment: Have you tried any clients already? Would you consider installing Windows on your Mac using bootcamp?

Comment: @FMRauanSagit No. I tried Jin and Raptor. Kibitz also, but it's buggy as all hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have choices:

i. [Kibitz](http://kibitz.berlios.de/Kibitz%20Home.html), implemented features are

- Playing and observing chess games on FICS
- Observing multiple games
- Chat with other users on FICS
- Support for chess variants including "Bughouse" and "Crazyhouse"

ii. [Raptor](http://chesshive.com/2011/08/raptor-chess-fics-desktop-client-for-mac/), FICS desktop client for Mac

iii. [Jin](http://www.jinchess.com/), which is Java based and can be executed on a Mac also.

iv. [XBoard](http://www.open-aurec.com/wbforum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=50428), a multi platform solution!

and such a pity that you can't try [BabasChess](http://www.babaschess.net/) (maybe you can use a emulator to execute it on your Mac)

Comment: Hello, I have found the lost source code from Kibitz on Berlios from the developer and am working to modernize the code. Shameless plug for project: https://github.com/fulldecent/kibitz

Comment: Just following up, this project is still moving and we have gotten it to compile on the latest Mac version now (10.11 El Capitan)

Answer (score 1):

When I switched to OSX I noticed that Babaschess would not run. Since I am a developer I started creating my own client.. Please, have a look and let me know what you think. It doesn't support chess engines to analyze positions, but saves your games as pgn.

http://www.macbeth-ficsclient.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you want something very simple to start with, try LightFICS:
http://lightfics.brrm.ru/

It's a native [Mac OS X FICS client](http://lightfics.brrm.ru/). It has no dependencies, is extremely easy to install and use.
It doesn't have any nice-to-haves, but you can save games as PGN and use other tools to analyse openings with engines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a mac, and i'm not a FICS user, here's what i found by googliing

http://sourceforge.net/projects/kibitz.berlios/

http://chesshive.com/2011/08/raptor-chess-fics-desktop-client-for-mac/

http://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/18kbm9/what_software_do_you_use_with_fics_on_mac_osx/

http://www.chesscircle.net/forums/showthread.php?2420-Macintosh-ICC-FICS-client

Comment: FYI, the kibitz link here is just the archived version when BerliOS unfortunately went dark. The other answer has the updated link for the currently maintained version of this project.

Comment: @FullDecent good to know for mac users, but as of right now, as im posting this comment, the other link gives server not found, sourceforge always works

Comment: Sorry, not the berlios one (that project is RIP), talking about the GitHub one

Answer (score 0):

ChessX is phenomenal. I can confirm it works under Mac OS Ventura:

https://chessx.sourceforge.io